# django.template.exceptions.TemplateDoesNotExist

Tags: django

I'm learning django, and I have a problem, I'm doing a virtual store and when I click on add a product to the shopping cart you should redirect me to another page, but can not find it, this is my code and my error:

django.template.exceptions.TemplateDoesNotExist: productos/carritocompras_form.html

## detalle.html

```
<div class="fixed-action-btn" style="bottom:90px;">
    <form action="{% url 'aniadir_carrito' %}" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <input type="hidden" name="usuario" value="{{request.user.pk}}">
        <input type="hidden" name="produto" value="{{object.pk}}">
        <input type="hidden" name="precio" value="{{object.precio}}">
        <button class="btn-floating btn-large red pulse">
            <i class="large material-icons">add_shopping_cart</i>
        </button>
    </form>
</div>
<div class="fixed-action-btn">
    <a class="btn-floating btn-large red pulse">
        <i class="large material-icons">add_shopping_cart</i>
    </a>
    <ul>
    </ul>
</div>
```

## url.py

```
    from django.conf import settings
from django.urls import include, path
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.contrib import admin
from django.views.generic import TemplateView
from django.views import defaults as default_views

from tienda.users.views import (
    Indice, ListarProductos, DetalleProducto, ComentarioProducto, Ingresar, Salir, CambiarPerfil,
    CarritoCompras, AniadirCarrito, ListarCarrito, ListarCarritoPendientes, ListarCarritoFinalizadas, EliminarCarrito
)


urlpatterns = [

    path('', Indice.as_view(), name="indice"),
    path("listado_productos", ListarProductos.as_view(), name="listado_productos"),
    path("detalle_producto/<int:pk>/", DetalleProducto.as_view(), name="detalle_producto"),
    path("crear_comentario/", ComentarioProducto.as_view(), name="crear_comentario"),
    path("ingresar/", Ingresar.as_view(), name="ingresar"),
    path("salir/", Salir.as_view(), name="salir"),

    path("editar_perfil/", CambiarPerfil.as_view(), name="editar_perfil"),

    path("aniadir_carrito", AniadirCarrito.as_view(), name="aniadir_carrito"),
    path("listar_carrito", ListarCarrito.as_view(), name="listar_carrito"),
    path("listar_pendientes", ListarCarritoPendientes.as_view(), name="listar_pendientes"),
    path("listar_finalizado", ListarCarritoFinalizadas.as_view(), name="listar_finalizado"),
    path("eliminar_carrito", EliminarCarrito.as_view(), name="eliminar_carrito"),

    # Django Admin, use {% url 'admin:index' %}
    path(settings.ADMIN_URL, admin.site.urls),

    # Your stuff: custom urls includes go here
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

## views.py

```
class AniadirCarrito(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model           = CarritoCompras
    fields          = ('usuario','producto', 'precio',)
    success_url     = reverse_lazy('indice')
    login_url       = 'ingresar'
```

## models.py

```
class CarritoCompras(models.Model):
    producto        = models.ForeignKey(Producto, related_name="producto_carrito", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    usuario         = models.ForeignKey(get_user_model(), related_name="carrito_usuario", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    precio          = models.IntegerField()
    direccion       = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    datos_payu      = models.CharField(max_length=600)
    comprado        = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    pendiente       = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return "{} {}".format(self.usuario)
```

Comment: The problem is exactly as your error says, `carritocompras_form.html` is missing. Check if it exists in your templates folder and if you're pointing to it correctly or not.

Comment: its no exist bro, i´m watching video course in udemy but no working for me :/

Comment: ok, it was stupid error in detalle.html > input name='produto'  | is name='producto',

Comment: Welcome to coding! :P